# Django: Dynamic filtering (OR & AND) using Q objects for arbitrary number of input

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-q

Suppose the input is,

```
f = ['f0_0', 'f1_0', 'f1_1', 'f2_0', 'f2_1', 'f2_2']
```

How to create query in the following way

```
model.objects.filter(Q(k = "f0_0"), Q(k = "f1_0") | Q(k = "f1_1"), Q(k = "f2_0") | Q(k = "f2_1") | Q(k = "f2_2"))
```

where 'k' remains same for all and the input can have arbitrary number of elements in the specified combination.

I've tried to chain up recursively using & and | operator on Q(), and also tried building filters using the reduce function. But I always end up in error "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why chaining of '|' and '&' operator is not working properly with Q(). But somehow got this to work by calling eval on string(looks kind of a work around than a solution)

```
fMap = {}
for opt in f:
    prefix = opt.split('_')[0]
    if not prefix in fMap:
        fMap[prefix] = 'Q(k="' + opt +'")'
    else:
        fMap[prefix] += '|Q(k="' + opt +'")'
model.objects.filter(*eval('[' + ','.join([v for k, v in fMap.iteritems()]) + ']'))
```